# DropDownList value into Linq query where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, linq

I am facing following problem. I want a search field with a DropDowList next to it, where user can pick an item for which he wants to search. I have to make it with this LINQ code not just a SQL query.

Here's my code:

```
var Metadata = from m in db.Metadatas
    join mm in db.Multimedias
    on m.multimediaID equals mm.multimediaID
    where (m.   { Here would i have the selected value from the dropdownlist. } .ToString().Contains(textboxvalue) ||
           mm.  { Here would i have the selected value from the dropdownlist. } .ToString().Contains(textboxvalue))
           && mm.filetype.ToString().Contains(radiobuttonvalue)
```

I want to put something like: "Dropdownlist.selectedvalue" into the area { Here would i have the selected value from the dropdownlist. }

I hope you guys understand my idea and problem.

Comment: what is your problem? you never state it.

Comment: I want to have my "dropdownlist.selectedvalue" in the area where i said: { Here would i have the selected value from the dropdownlist. }

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are doing join on in your linq statement.  That is not necessary if you Linq already knows about the relationship between the objects because there is a foreign key relationship setup in the database.

What you can do is this:

```
var Metedata = db.Metadatas;

switch(Dropdownlist.selectedvalue)
{
  case "one":
    Metadata = Metadata.Where(m => m.{selected value field}.Contains(textboxvalue));
    break;

  case "two":
    Metadata = Metadata.Where(m => m.{selected value field}.Contains(textboxvalue));
    break;

  //More use cases
}
```

I am not sure what you will be selecting out of the list when you are done, but if it involves related objects (e.g. Multimedias) then you might want to look into DataLoadOptions (LinqToSQL) or .Include() (EntityFrameworks).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sql query:

if(supportgrp.SelectedItem.Text == "All")

sql ="SELECT * FROM QlyData where Date >='" + txtstartdate.Text + "' and Date<='" + txtenddate.Text + "'";

else

sql ="SELECT * FROM QlyData where Date >='" + txtstartdate.Text + "' and Date<='" + txtenddate.Text + "' and suppgrp = '" + supportgrp.Text + "'";